# git push broken after upgrading to Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, git, ubuntu-16.04

I've run into a snag with `git` after upgrading -

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. git version 2.9.2

Trying to push results in:
    git push

```
git-remote-https: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4: undefined symbol: __gmpn_cnd_add_n
```

I can fix this if I do:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10.bak
```

However, after a restart, the issue returns. Does anyone have ideas for a permanent solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same error (with `git clone`) and the following command solved it:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*
```

[[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279649/123965)]

Comment: Apparently, removing all these symlinks is the trick. Not just the one problematic one.